# Can I get VM windows outside the VMWare workstation window?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I have an XP VM in VMWare Workstation 6.5.  I think read somewhere that its possible to drag windows that belong to programs running on the VM outside the VMWare window, so they act like normal desktop windows.  I want to do this so I can still use all 3 monitors of my desktop for programs running on the VM.  My company's VPN sortware doesn't run on 64 bit operating systems, so I have to remote in via a 32bit virtual machine.

Is this possible to do, or am I imagining things?

Comment: Never even realized this was possible! Definitely a feature that's worth a +100!!! (And yes, I have the same problem.)

Comment: VirtualBox does it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the VM is running, go to VMware Workstation's "View" menu and choose Unity mode.

You must have the VMware Client stuff installed in the client for this to work.

Comment: awesome, that does the trick.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that it doesn't seem to work with several combinations Vista x64 or Win7 x64 and some video cards (like my Nvidia /sob)