# Unity mode in VirtualPC?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, vmware-unity

As I read from [this Q](https://superuser.com/questions/49122/can-i-get-vm-windows-outside-the-vmware-workstation-window), there's an option in VMWare that allows dragging windows outside the VMWare environment. Great feature. But how about [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Virtual_PC)? Does it also offer something like this Unity mode and if so, how?

Addendum: The host is running either Vista or XP.

Comment: I edited my answer with new information. Short answer, it's not possible with Virtual PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar to unity mode is available only in the version of Virtual PC shipped with **Windows 7**. That's how XP mode works, an XP app window will appear alongside all the other Windows 7 windows, but without being themed (it still has the normal Windows XP theme, not the Aero theme).

[image]

In the image above you can see that one of the Office windows has the default Windows XP theme. That's similar to unity, it's outside the VM.

**Edit**: running something similar to Unity is not possible in earlier versions of Virtual PC, it's a feature limited to only the version that ships with Windows 7; this version can't be installed in XP or Vista.

Comment: It’s good to note that that feature is *only* available in Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate. Not the Home Premium or other weird Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Virtual PC does not have this feature. [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) on Windows 7 however does support this for Windows Virtual Machines.

Strangely this is a feature more common on MacOS Virtual Applications, since VirtualBox, VMWare and Parallels all support it. On Windows it has taken a bit longer to get running. VirtualBox has supported this on Linux for a while as well.